# GWT- dynamically make widgets non-editable

Tags: java, sql, gwt

As per my requirements, I need to make a widget textbox prepopulate based on a selection, then under specific scenerios make the prepopulated field non-editable (from editable) without the page reloading.

The prepopulation works fine, but when I try to change my widget textbox to non-editable from the code (a validator), nothing changes. Of course I can easily make a field editable or noneditable easily on page load by setting my widget attribute directly in sql developer. But  I need this to happen on the 'fly'.

So what is the proper strategy?

My thought is the widget is activated on load, and if I change the widget property I need a way to tell it to look there again w/o reloading the entire page?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `TextBox#setReadOnly` should work.

Comment: Issue has been resolved. I was correct in needing to reload the widget i set the read only status too. 1 line of code fixed it. Seem's so simple now :)

Comment: @TheJavaBeast How did you reload the widget though?